# How to get multiple values of ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

Can anyone tell me how to get multiple values of `ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId`?

Accessing the Chatter Attachments Via `ContentDocumentLink` seems to work fine for project using the query .

```ape
List<ContentDocumentLink> lstContentDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, 
    ContentDocument.Title, 
    ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name, 
    ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate , 
    LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                      WHERE LinkedEntityId =: milestone_project.Id ];
```

but when i am running the same query for the List of Ids , For Example

```apex
List<ContentDocumentLink> lstContentDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, 
    ContentDocument.Title, 
    ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name, 
    ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate , 
    LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                      WHERE LinkedEntityId =: List Of Related Milestone Ids  ];
```

It is throwing an exception

> ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id, ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator.

So can someone suggest a solution for this.

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

For list of ids, You should use IN.

Example:

```apex
List lstContentDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, 
                             ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name, 
                             ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate , LinkedEntity.Name 
                      FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                      WHERE LinkedEntityId 
                      IN :List Of Related Milestone Ids ];
```

Comment: Actually `=` is a perfectly fine operator against collections and works exactly the same as `IN`.